# Exceptions from both try block and try-with-resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) says

> However, in this example, if the methods `readLine` and `close` both throw exceptions, then the method `readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock` throws the exception thrown from the `finally` block; the exception thrown from the `try` block is suppressed. In contrast, in the example `readFirstLineFromFile`, **if exceptions are thrown from both the `try` block and the `try`-with-resources statement**, then the method `readFirstLineFromFile` throws the exception thrown from the `try` block; the exception thrown from the `try`-with-resources block is suppressed. In Java SE 7 and later, you can retrieve suppressed exceptions; see the section Suppressed Exceptions for more information.

I don't understand the bold part

> ... **if exceptions are thrown from both the `try` block and the `try`-with-resources statement** ...

How can an exception be thrown from both the `try`-with-resources statement and the `try` block ? If the exception is thrown from the `try`-with-resources statement, it means that resource initialization failed. In this case, `try` block is never executed. Thus the previous statement can't happen.

I must have misunderstood this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and how `try`-with-resources works. Can you provide example where the bold statement actually happens ?

---

Mentioned methods

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

```
static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path)
                                                     throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: An exception can be thrown during the ```close``` portion as well. So if the try block throws an exception, try-with-resources will attempt to close the filehandle, and if that _also_ throws an exception, then this would cover the case where both of them throw exceptions.

From the same page:

"In the example writeToFileZipFileContents, an exception can be thrown from the try block, and **up to two exceptions can be thrown from the try-with-resources statement when it tries to close the ```ZipFile``` and ```BufferedWriter``` objects**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can an exception be thrown from both the try-with-resources statement and the try block ? If the exception is thrown from the try-with-resources statement, it means that resource initialization failed.

The *try-with-resources statement* not only initializes but also closes the resource, and closing *may* throw an exception.

This sentence comes right after a description of a similar situation when using *try-finally*, and compares it with *try-with-resources*.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the scope of what documentation calls "try-with-resources". I assumed it is only resource initialization, but it also includes resource closing.

Answer (score 0):

oracle documentation sucks. i wouldn't call try-with-resources block for implicit close methods, but rather for constructors and doc doesn't say anything about exception in constructors

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33436625)